# trying to understand mongo $unset

Tags: mongodb, unset

If I have a document like

```
{ mykey:1, myarr: [8, 9, 10] }
```

and using the `$unset` operator with the array position to unset the 
0th element as:

```
{$unset:{myarr.0:1}}
```

my document becomes

`{mykey:1, myarr:[9, 10]}`

Now, is the value "9" the 0th element or 1st element of my array?

Answer (score 1):

When used with $unset to an array element, $unset replaces the matching element with null rather than removing the matching element from the array. This behavior keeps consistent the array size and element positions. 

In your case 9 is 1st element of your array. for ref [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/)

Comment: Thank you @Murugan for your answer. In this case is there a way to remove the element using the array position? I found $pull removes an array element based on a condition of the value. Is this the only way?

Comment: I think $pull is the only way to remove elements from array